# c++ Elements lost when stored in a map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, dfa

I'm trying for several days to simulate a non-deterministic finite automata, using a map I'm storing state transitions, exactly as indicated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589240/insert-pair-into-map-in-c).

The problem is they are missing the nondeterministic transitions, ie those which by the same symbol, lead me to different states. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator> // for ostream_iterator

using namespace std;

int main (){

    freopen ("testMap.in", "r", stdin);
    int testCases;
    int i, j;

    int stateOrigin, stateDestination;
    char transitionCharacter ;
    int numberTransitions=8;

        typedef map<pair<int, char>, int> transitions;
        transitions trans;

          for (j=0; j<numberTransitions;j++){
             cin>> stateOrigin>>stateDestination>>transitionCharacter;
             trans.insert(transitions::value_type(std::make_pair(stateOrigin,transitionCharacter), stateDestination ));
        }

        map<pair<int, char>, int>::iterator p = trans.begin();

       for( p = trans.begin(); p != trans.end(); p++ ){
         cout << p->first.first<< " "<<p->first.second<<" "<<p->second<<endl;
       }

return 0;
}
```

When I print the entire contents of the map, this tell me:

```
0 a 0
1 b 1
1 c 2
3 d 4
4 d 4
```

and the expected output is:

```
0 0 a
0 1 a
1 1 b
1 2 c
1 3 c
3 4 d
4 4 d
4 5 d
```

What am I doing wrong. In another question,  answered that the best way to simulate the transitions of nondeterministic finite automaton is to use map, but use map is appropriate in this type of problem or can be solved in any way?. Why these values ​​are lost?

It is convenient to change the map structure ? i.e:

```
typedef map<pair<int, int>, char> transitions;
```

Comment: Are all the  keys  in your data set  unique? If not try using multimap instead.

Comment: What's the expected output? `std::map` doesn't allow duplicate keys, so you can't have f.ex. ((0,a),0) and ((0,a),1) in it at the same time.

Comment: @jrok I edit the question with the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map is a `1-to-1` relationship between a key and a value, so it can represent a deterministic automata.

A non-deterministic automata can be represented by a `1-to-many` associative container.

I.e. you need a `std::multimap` or you can keep on using a `std::map` with the value type a different container:

```
 typedef map<pair<int, int>, vector<char> > transitions;
```

so you can have multiple `char` values for each `int` pair.

Comment: What is the difference between:
`typedef map <pair <int, int>, char> transitions;`
and:
`typedef map<pair<int, int>, vector<char> > transitions;`

Comment: @novaKid Read the last sentence of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the typedef, it is legal.

In std::map the keys must be unique therefore i am guessing you have some same pair values. In these cases please try to use std::multimap since it can store multiple keyed values in it.

Edit: Ok, the problem is:

```
map<pair<int, char>, int>::iterator p = trans.begin();
```

you have a pair. You expect to see:

```
0 0 a
0 1 a
```

However the keys are: (0, a) and (0, a) therefore the map ignores one.

You can avoid this by making the map as: (changing int and char order)

```
typedef map<pair<int, int>, char> transitions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a map is a pair your insert is always looking for a pair<>, since your first element in the map is a pair, try this code

```
 trans.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(stateOrigin,transitionCharacter), stateDestination ));
```